# data() method does not exist in QueryDocumentSnapshot in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am simply trying to get a document's data in one of my firebase callable functions, I already know its ID from a previous query.

The problem is that the resulting object from the `[...].doc(id).get()` method does not have the `.data()` method or the `exists` member.

I have tried listing the object's properties using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(snapshot);` and couldn't find `exists` or `data()`.

Getting the document's reference works using `ref`, but I don't have access to the other methods/members.

Here's how I get my data using two queries (notice my console.log calls) :

```
return firestore.collection("/teams").where("login", "==", data.login).get()
    .then( (snapshot) => {
        if(!snapshot.empty) {
            user = snapshot.docs[0].data().login;
            id = snapshot.docs[0].id;
            console.log(snapshot.docs);
            return firestore.collection("/passwords").doc(id).get();
        } else {
            return {
                success: false,
                error: 2
            };
        }
    })
    .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        if(snapshot.hasOwnProperty("exists") && snapshot.exists) {
            return bcrypt.compare(data.password, snapshot.data().password);
        } else {
            return {
                success: false,
                error: 2
            };
        }
    })
```

Here's the output from my first console.log (I've cut off the validator part to save on space) :

```
[ QueryDocumentSnapshot {
    _ref: 
     DocumentReference {
       _firestore: [Object],
       _validator: [Object],
       _referencePath: [Object] },
    _fieldsProto: 
     { colour: [Object],
       name: [Object],
       teammates: [Object],
       login: [Object] },
    _serializer: 
     Serializer {
       timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true,
       createReference: [Function] },
    _validator: 
     Validator {
       ... },
    _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1553530847, _nanoseconds: 875308000 },
    _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1553530458, _nanoseconds: 66673000 },
    _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1553530458, _nanoseconds: 66673000 } } ]
```

Here's the output from my second console.log :

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot {
  _ref: 
   DocumentReference {
     _firestore: 
      Firestore {
        _validator: [Object],
        _clientPool: [Object],
        _settingsFrozen: true,
        _clientInitialized: [Object],
        _initalizationSettings: [Object],
        _serializer: [Object],
        _timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true,
        _referencePath: [Object],
        _preferTransactions: true,
        _lastSuccessfulRequest: 1553530848171 },
     _validator: 
      Validator {
        ... },
     _referencePath: 
      ResourcePath {
        segments: [Array],
        projectId: 'rally-gccd',
        databaseId: '(default)' } },
  _fieldsProto: 
   { password: 
      { stringValue: '$2b$10$Xy1fCI.mKxvBhCHGimNqK.mPGU4lb1p.6pQgqacnnAUYjPomIWyaa',
        valueType: 'stringValue' } },
  _serializer: 
   Serializer {
     timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true,
     createReference: [Function] },
  _validator: 
   Validator {
     ... },
  _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1553530848, _nanoseconds: 114930000 },
  _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1553530458, _nanoseconds: 341760000 },
  _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1553530458, _nanoseconds: 341760000 } }
```

What's weird here is that I can use .data() on the first snapshot just fine, but doesn't exist on the second snapshot, even though both of the logs indicate that both snapshots are of the QueryDocumentSnapshot type.

Comment: Can you share your full Cloud Function code? How do you define `firestore`?

Comment: It's pretty large, since there are several functions defined. But here's how I defined my `firestore` variable : `const admin = require('firebase-admin');` `const firestore = admin.firestore();`

Comment: You are sure that the first `snapshot` is not empty and that the value of `id` is correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my actual `snapshot` is valid, as you can see my document's data in the `_fieldsProto` member, with my needed stringValue in the console.log of my snapshot.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the output of console.log in your code is what you're showing in the question?  I would expect your console.log to show one of two things, either a DocumentSnapshot (not a QueryDocumentSnapshot) or a static object on error.

Comment: I've edited my post to better explain my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the issue by nesting the second document get Promise inside the first document query Promise. This is less than ideal since it's a bit more messy, but at least it works.